# Optimization design for big file IO

Tags: video, file-io, operating-system, filesystems, hard-drive

Say if there is a program running on a Linux server, which reads a big file on disk, ex) a raw video, and generates outputs based on some user inputs.

The server is going to receive requests from many many requests of that program, therefore the file reading is duplicated in every process of requests.

Is there a way to have some optimization across requests?  the system looks going to be IO bound.

More concrete example, 
The system is taking user's text and render the text on each frame of a sample video and save to another output video.  each user gets their own output video.
The sample video is one static file, read-only and saved on server's HDD.

So if do nothing, all the requests, i.e. processes, open their own FILE IO and read through the big giant raw video.  So wondering if any optimization can help reduce disk bandwidth?   can memory mapped file help?

Comment: Obviously, such optimizations are possible and operating systems implement them.

Comment: The server is using CentOS/Linux.  is there already some known OS features that could help?